# Symfony2 security context does not see FOSUserBundle groups. Why?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i am created user and group entities.
After it, i am created user named admin, and group for this user, and gave a ROLE_CMS to a new group.

But, when i try to check user`s role, i got there:

```
$this->getUser()->getRoles(); // array('ROLE_CMS', 'ROLE_USER');
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_CMS'); // false
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'); // true
```

**EDIT:** Solved. I am relogin in system

Answer (score 0):

The Security component is not linked to any database. You persistence layer with User/Group play no role with the authorization process.

This question should help you get a bit further on this matter. The essence is the same.

[Recursive roles with custom user provider entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937436/recursive-roles-with-custom-user-provider-entity/14938808#comment20965504_14938808)

Comment: FOSUserBundle does not do it for me?

Comment: Yes, FOSUserBundle does that for you. Are you sure you followed all the steps described in https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md ?

Comment: So, do you know how confirm group`s changes without relogin a user?